# Devices appearing and disappearing from the network

Tags: windows, networking, local-area-network

I have recently noticed a weird problem where clients and servers are only sometimes visible to browse on the network. All connectivity is good, I might add, and all devices can be browsed to by UNC path and are responding to ping. Nothing has changed on the network to my knowledge since this problem has started a few weeks ago. We are running Server 2019 domain controllers and W10 client PCs. Sometimes, all devices are visible and then this will drop off after a period to only being around four or five other client PCs being visible. Any research I have found points to the Function Discovery Provider Host, Function Discover Resource Publication, SSDP Discovery and UPnP Device Host services being responsible for this but restarting (or starting) these services does not solve the problem. I've checked the firewall settings and also our Sophos Endpoint Protection and neither of these are at fault.

I understand that SMB1 has been deprecated by MS due to it not being secure, but most of our client PCs have this active due to being required for scanning documents from our MFD copiers to their desktops. Not sure if this might be a contributing factor or not.

Any suggestions are welcome as I'm going round in circles with this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the IT try to deactivate that as it can allow a user to breach your network by discovering all your gears and it's kind of thing that broadcast on all your switchs. Why you want to enforce that ?

Map the drive(s) to the users, no need for discovering the network.

If you *really* need a list of PC to naviguate I would suggest to, *hrm* .. , deploy WINS service...

Comment: My issue is that everything was working fine until a few weeks ago. Users do have mapped drives for their documents but sometimes there is the requirement to browse to locations that they do not have mapped, and would not ordinarily need to have mapped. Nothing has been deactivated on our network.